# Google Recaptcha: Blocked a frame with origin "https://www.google.com" from accessing a cross-origin frame

Tags: javascript, reactjs, iframe, recaptcha, same-origin-policy

I have integrated google recaptcha in vite-react-ts app and created the build of that.

```
const script = document.createElement('script');
script.src = url;
script.async = true;
script.defer = true;
script.onload = renderCaptcha;
document.body.appendChild(script);

return () => {
    document.body.removeChild(script);
}
```

```
const renderCaptcha = () => {
    if (window?.grecaptcha) {
        try {
            if (captchaRef.current.captcha) {
                captchaRef.current = { ...captchaRef.current, pendingCaptcha: true };
                window?.grecaptcha.reset(captchaRef.current.captcha);
            } else {
                const captcha = window?.grecaptcha.render(captchaContainerRef.current, {
                    sitekey: CAPTCHA_V2_KEY,
                    callback: () => {
                        captchaRef.current = { ...captchaRef.current, pendingCaptcha: false };
                    },
                    'expired-callback': (data: any) => {
                        console.log("expired")
                        console.log(data)
                    },
                    'error-callback': (error: any) => {
                        console.log("error")
                        console.log(error)
                    }
                });
                captchaRef.current = { ...captchaRef.current, captcha, pendingCaptcha: true };
            }
        } catch (e) {
            console.error('captcha generation error', e);
        }
    }
};
```

JSX

```
 <div ref={captchaContainerRef} id="signin_captcha" />
```

Now i am trying to load this build using script tag in other app.

I am getting the error
`Uncaught DOMException: Blocked a frame with origin "https://www.google.com" from accessing a cross-origin frame.`

- I am running the app locally using http-server with ssl
- I have whitelisted localhost in re captcha dashboard
- I am expecting it to load recaptcha properly

Comment: I don't know if this is the case but, have you checked your browser extensions? Maybe you have an extension that is blocking the script.

Comment: No i dont have any extension at all @Klian

Answer (score 1):

Did some research to find a way, looks like its not possible as its a blocker from browser itself.

Only solution i can do now is to attach the recaptcha with document body intead of my app, which will give access to DOM of recaptcha and it will work.

Answer (score 0):

Google's ReCAPTCHA and Chrome team are in conflict. They've made some broken code, especially v2 of recaptcha.

Even if you direct the api.js to http:// it redirects it internally and then tries to scan for a window.yoursite.a-12945u12 type of property and it can't because it's trying to read it from an iframe it places into your website.

Webpack dev server doesn't allow it even with "cross-origin allowed".

Neither does any AWS infrastructure settings to allow cross-origin, or specifically https://google.com

```
Uncaught DOMException: Failed to read a named property 'a-9tu39a56hre3' from 'Window': Blocked a frame with origin "https://www.google.com" from accessing a cross-origin frame.
at Q.Yv (https://www.gstatic.com/recaptcha/releases/MHBiAvbtvk5Wb2eTZHoP1dUd/recaptcha__en.js:1004:346)
at Array.<anonymous> (https://www.gstatic.com/recaptcha/releases/MHBiAvbtvk5Wb2eTZHoP1dUd/recaptcha__en.js:531:92)
at Object.init (https://www.gstatic.com/recaptcha/releases/MHBiAvbtvk5Wb2eTZHoP1dUd/recaptcha__en.js:1011:141)
at https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api2/bframe?hl=en&v=MHBiAvbtvk5Wb2eTZHoP1dUd&k=6LcrDmQpAAAAABDVugX2X1AuLCoiEBNR5PETxkP5:184:30
```

Solution: Build your own captcha with better code and let's reduce our reliance on Google's badly tested products.